# Will Casper be "backwards compatible" with currently issued tokens such as ERC20 tokens?

Tags: contract-development, tokens, proof-of-stake, casper, protocol

With Casper now available for testing, does the protocol work with regular ERC20 tokens?

For example if Casper becomes the main protocol for the whole Ethereum network and the old PoW method is gone, will this effect tokens already issued?

If creating a token now that wants long-term functionality with the best Ethereum possible, should I be doing something different than creating a regular token, to ensure that it is fully functional with Casper in the future?

I appreciate input on this as I cannot find much information anywhere regarding Casper and "backwards compatibility".

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Casper will not impact already deployed or new Smart Contracts(including ERC20 tokens).

Casper FFG is just a modification to the underlying Consensus protocol introducing a PoW/PoS hybrid model and quick and dependable finality;it doesn't affect Solidity or the EVM, so you don't need to make any modification to existing code.

Comment: Thank you. Will the same be the case for Casper CBC (no effect on solidity or the EVM) ?

Comment: Correct, afaik Casper CBC also isn't going to affect Solidity or the EVM.

Comment: As convenient as it would be to take your word for it, some explanation of how, and a link to a credible source would be needed for this to be a valid answer.

Comment: @Kevin
Well the question is almost a year old and it was originally asked at a time when the roadmap and technical details for ETH 2.0 were significantly different from what they are now.
Still the current consensus among core devs for the eth ecosystem seem to be that neither the switch to PoS nor the introduction of the sharded architecture will affect smart contract development:
https://ethresear.ch/t/smart-contract-languages-for-ethereum-2-0-serenity-use/5185